# Visualizing the zeros of a function of three variables

Tags: equation-solving, functions

I have a function `f[x_, y_, z_] := (x - y) (z^2 - x*y)` of three variables `x`, `y` and `z`. The conditions for `f[x, y, z]` to have zeros are `x=y` or `z^2 = x*y`. Now if I *impose* the condition that that  `f[x, y, z]`  is a *non-negative* function, then how do the above conditions for zeros get affected for a *fixed* `x` while varying `y` and `z`?

Comment: You can use `RegionFunction` in `ContourPlot3D[]` to impose your constraints.

Comment: `f[x_, y_, z_] := (x - y) (z^2 - x*y);
ContourPlot3D[
 f[x, y, z] == 0 // Evaluate, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, {x, -5, 5}, 
 PlotPoints -> 30, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, f[x, y, z] >= 0], 
 RegionBoundaryStyle -> None, AxesLabel -> {"y", "z", "x"}, 
 LabelStyle -> {10, Bold}]`

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 1; 
f[x_, y_, z_] := Max[{(x - y) (z^2 - x*y), 0}];
ContourPlot3D[f[x, y, z], {x, -a, a}, {y, -a, a}, {z, -a, a}]
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

This is probably more exactly what you are asking.  Mathematica has a bit of a problem plotting the surface where the function is zero or near zero:

```
a = 1;
g[x_, y_, z_] := (x - y) (z^2 - x*y);
f[x_, y_, z_] := Piecewise[{{g[x, y, z], g[x, y, z] >= 0}}, Undefined]
ContourPlot3D[f[x, y, z], {x, -a, a}, {y, -a, a}, {z, -a, a}]
```

[image]